# Apache on virtualbox with docroot on shared folder creates folders with different owner

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualbox

I have Mac OS 10.8 as host system and CentOS 6 as guest system with Virtual Box 4.1.18
I create shared folder and successfully mount it to guest system.

Line in /etc/fstab

```
php   /var/www/centos.dev     vboxsf  defaults,uid=500,gid=500  0 0
```

So its mounted with my user. But when apache creates folders or files on this folder they have my user and group as owner as well! So apache don't have write permissions to files it was created itself.
In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf I have

```
User apache
Group apache
```

And files not on vbox shared folder created with this user and group.

Why is it happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Disable [`sendfile`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile) mechanism and try again:

```
EnableSendfile Off
```